# How to get a keyboard with microphone?

Tags: android, speech-to-text

I want to implement a speech to text in my android application. I am looking for the keyboard which has microphone as one of the keys in it like iphone. How can i achieve the same.

Comment: You can create a custom keyboard onto which in declaring buttons layout have a button with your own constant value, and onKey(i.e. overriden method of InputMethodService) check for that constant and trigger your speech to text login

Comment: hi, thank u can u help by giving example  code.

Comment: you can get the sample code from google itself, i am posting it as an answer and posting the code too.

Answer (score 2):

Sample code: https://github.com/Miserlou/Android-SDK-Samples/tree/master/SoftKeyboard

and what you have to do is:
suppose i am doing it on pressing "Q", its key is 113(refer res>xml>qwerty.xml)
then on overridden method in Softkeyboard.java

```
public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
    if(primaryCode == 113){
     // write your login for triggering speech to text here  and add it to mComposing to see it on UI
    }
}
```

Comment: ok thank you so much ashwani I will try to do with the help of your sample code

Comment: support the answer if it helped

Comment: accept it to close this question

Comment: let me try it first please.